# Substring of a string based on condition

Tags: java, substring, string-utils

I have a string like below (read from a file and stored in a String)

```
<textmessages>
<textMessage timestamp="1424708212905">
<property name="tcs_car_kind" value="M32"/>
<property name="prev_cmdy_abrv" value="AUTOS"/>
<text><![CDATA[event_code="AP"]]></text>
</textMessage>
<textMessage timestamp="1424708212902">
<property name="shp_prim" value=""/>
<property name="prev_cmdy_abrv" value="AUTOS"/>
<text><![CDATA[event_code="CP"]]></text>
</textMessage>
<textMessage timestamp="1424708212902">
<property name="co_part_frm_nbr" value=""/>
<property name="prev_cmdy_abrv" value="AUTOS"/>
<text><![CDATA[event_code="LP"]]></text>
</textMessage>
</textmessages>
```

Requirement:

If string values matches to 'event_code="CP"' then I need to return complete data in between `<textmessage> ---- </textmessage>` as shown below.

```
<textMessage timestamp="1424708212902">
<property name="co_part_frm_nbr" value=""/>
<property name="shp_prim" value=""/>
<property name="prev_cmdy_abrv" value="AUTOS"/>
<text><![CDATA[event_code="CP"]]></text>
</textMessage>
```

Comment: used stingtokenizer but of no use..:(

Comment: use DOM or SAX parser. I see someone has already suggested DOM so here is SAX: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html

Answer (score 0):

A combination of those might help http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html

Search for 'event_code="CP" 
with find() or match()
if is there...

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("pattern here");
    if(p.matcher(content).find()){...}`

Other option is to use xml parses, but regex are really simple for what you want.

if the pattern is really constant, yo can even use indexOf to go faster on your searches... 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

if they are on the same location, then just reading from there is enough..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to parse that String as a XML using DOM?
With this you just have to compare the value of each "text" node and if it's value matches you return the whole parent node, as String for example...

Here is a basic sample of how it DOM works in Java: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/